# Django + multiprocessing.dummy.Pool + sleep = weird result

Tags: python, django, multithreading

In my Django application, I want to do some work in background when a certain view is requested. To that end, I created a `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` of workers, and whenever that URL is called, I start a new process on it. The task to be executed in background can have to do some retries with a certain timeout between them.

Since this whole thing is executed, so to speak, not on a UI thread, I thought I'd use `sleep` for timeouts. When I unittest this arrangement, everything works fine, but when this runs in Django, the thread gets to the sleep statement and then never wakes up, but when I restart the Django app, the thread gets past the sleep statement and then is immediately killed by the restart. I know I could schedule retries using `Timer`s, but I wanted a simpler solution.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
POOL = Pool(settings.POOL_WORKERS)

def background_task(arg):
    refresh = True
    try:
        for i in range(settings.GET_RETRY_LIMIT):
            status, result = (arg, refresh=refresh)
            refresh = False
            if status is Statuses.OK:
                return result
            if i < settings.GET_RETRY_LIMIT - 1:
                sleep(settings.GET_SLEEP_TIME)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)

    return []


def do_background_work(arg):
    POOL.apply_async(
        background_task,
        (arg)
    )


def my_view(request):
    arg = get_arg_from_request(request)
    do_background_work(arg)
    return Response("Ok")
```

**UPD:** By the way, turns out that the workers are most probably killed by `Harakiri`

Comment: Don't do this. Use a proper offline processor, ie Celery.

Comment: It was my initial idea, but our management says implementing it could be too long. Meanwhile, I'll read up on Celery.